# Check if string starts with a list of values & doesn't contain a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, startswith

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Jim', 'CF'], ['Toby', 'RW'], ['Joe', 'RWF'], ['Tom', 'RAMF'], ['John', 'RWB']], columns=['Name', 'Position'])
```

I want to obtain a subset of this dataframe such that we only have subjects who:

- Has `Position =` 'RW', 'RWF', or 'RAMF'

**I need to do this in one line of code**
I can currently do this in two lines:

```
RW = df[df['Position'].str.startswith(('RW', 'RAMF', 'RWF'), na = False)]
RW = RW[RW['Position'].str.contains('RWB')==False]
```

The issue is that subjects with position `'RWB'` show up when subsetting by `str.startswith('RW')`. Therefore, I have to specify in the second line to remove these `'RWB'`.

**Is it possible to do this in one line of code??**

Answer (score 1):

If need test starting of strings use:

```
RW = df[df['Position'].str.match('RW|RAMF|RWF', na = False) & 
        ~df['Position'].str.contains('RWB', na = False)]
print (RW)
   Name Position
1  Toby       RW
2   Joe      RWF
3   Tom     RAMF
```

Or:

```
RW = df[df['Position'].str.startswith(('RW', 'RAMF', 'RWF'), na = False) & 
        ~df['Position'].str.contains('RWB', na = False)]
print (RW)
   Name Position
1  Toby       RW
2   Joe      RWF
3   Tom     RAMF
```

If need test if exist values of tuple in column:

```
RW = df[df['Position'].isin(('RW', 'RAMF', 'RWF'))]

print (RW)
   Name Position
1  Toby       RW
2   Joe      RWF
3   Tom     RAMF
```